# Non-Randomized Block Design?

Tags: experiment-design, random-allocation, blocking

Suppose I am running a $2^2$ factorial design in two blocks. Denote the factors as A and B and the four treatment combinations as $(1), a, b$ and $ab$. Consider the blocking arrangement:
`-------------------
| Block1  | Block2 |
|---------|--------|
| (1)     | a      |
| ab      | b      |`

Now usually we assume that within each block, the treatment combinations are randomly assigned. However, suppose I impose the restriction that instead, within each block, the treatment combinations must be assigned in the  order as above (e.g. in Block 1, assign $(1)$ first, then $ab$. Similarly for Block 2). How can this design be analyzed? Does some kind of Order factor need to be considered?

Comment: It's a shame no one answered this. I do not have enough rep to set a bounty. I would be interested in people's thoughts on this.